# WebAPI validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I typically have ApiController methods that look like this

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage DoSomething(int someId)
{
  var someObj = Session.Get<SomeObj>(someId);
  if (someObj == null)
  {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
  }

  Do something...
}
```

I want to get rid of the if condition. I could just let a NullPointerException be thrown but I want to be able specify which HTTP status code to return. I would like to move the if condition to some validation class and perform the validation in OnActionExecuting perhaps.

I have used FluentValidation with WebAPI before and it would be nice to have a syntax like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.SomeId).Must(x => someObjectExists()).WithMessage("SomeObject wasn't found").WithHTTPStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

... where WithHTTPStatusCode would be the method that solves my problem.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: imo your proposed solution using FluentValidation is far more verbose (and consequently less readable) than a simple `if` statement.

Comment: I agree with @ByteBlast. Instead of the fluent configuration or if statement, I would create an extension on object to return 404 when null. Still lets you return other statues when needed and is a bit more readable.

Comment: Definitely wouldn't extend on `System.Object` pollutes your intellisense big time.

Comment: Ah yea I meant his SomeObj. Maybe if he has a base class his vms extend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool name!

I want to recommend this approach to you. Create a new class you define, called ServiceNotFoundException or something similar, and have it inherit from HttpResponseException, passing in a 404 not found as the constructor like so:

```
 public class ServiceNotFoundException : HttpResponseException
    {
        public ServiceNotFoundException() : base(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {

        }
    }
```

now in your Session.Get,  you should throw the exception if the entity isn't found in there (so keep this logic outside of your controller).

This way, if multiple controllers use your service, it will throw an exception in all cases. Because you inherit from HttpResponseException and throw NotFound, it will return a 404. If you need specific text/messages to go along with it, play around with the constructor and you'll see base() has an HttpResponseMessage you can throw in there alternately (perhaps set the specific message text in the response).

If you prefer to do this logic in the controller, you can throw the exception there anyway, but you should try not to repeat yourself!

Let me know if any questions!

Answer (score 1):

I like to handle this more silently because it keeps whomever is hitting the WebAPI Endpoint from knowing whether they are missing a needed variable.

```
        [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        public ServiceResult Login(JObject args)
        {
            var retVal = new ServiceResult {Success = false};
            JToken tokenValue;
            var email = string.Empty;
            var password = string.Empty;

            if (args.TryGetValue("email", out tokenValue))
            {
                email = args.Value<string>("email");
            }

            if (args.TryGetValue("password", out tokenValue))
            {
                password = args.Value<string>("password");
            }

            var user = Services.Users.GetByEmail(email, true);

            if (null != user || null != user.Id)
            {
                return Services.Authentication.AuthenticateSignIn(user, password, true);

            }

            retVal.Data = tokenValue;
            return retVal;
        }
```

If variables are missing, by default it should error out before it gets to the Endpoint unless you have the App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs set to

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
```

If you don't like the IF conditions, you could always use an Assert after you grab your variables.  Good luck!

Comment: If you were to create a base class APIController where you always accept JObjects, and then search for missing parameters - you could construct a single class that returns the various HTTP Status Codes for missing information or data, as well.

Answer (score 1):

why not use the standard model validation? are you using Entity Framework? you can achieve this using data annotations on your pocos or perhaps creating a model based on whatever you need, in your case a class with a single property will do just fine.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutOrder(int id, Order order)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }...
```

Order model would look like this...

```
    public partial class Order
    {
[Required]
 public int id { get; set; }
}
```